# Do I need to install Apache Spark and/or Scala to run a jUnit?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, junit

I am very new to Apache Spark framework, trying to setup my first jUnit like follows:

```
package com.sample.ccspark;

import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.SharedJavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class SimpleTest extends SharedJavaSparkContext {

    @Test
    public void initializationWorks()  {
        List<Integer> list = asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = jsc().parallelize(list);
        assertThat(rdd.count(), is(list.size()));
    }
}
```

with the following dependencies in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.holdenkarau</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0_0.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

everything happily compiles, however when running I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-6" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
scala/runtime/AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp
```

I do not have Spark or Scala installed locally yet, was under impression that testing framework should take care of all dependencies. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure but when you have this error: `NoClassDefFoundError` maybe it just means the Simple Class doesn't exist.
I think you cannot write SimpleTest if Simple doesn't exist. I might be wrong.

Comment: Judging from IntelliJ, the AbstractPartialFunction is present for the jUnit itself. In my understanding this has something to do with test trying to initialize Spark runtime as a separate process (this is just my theory) and not having correct class path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the artifacts names

`<artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.11</artifactId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>`

the last number is the version of Scala. I guess you should select only one for both cases.

Comment: That was it! Changed to spark-core_2.11 and it all works now :)